# Using dashboard uploader instead of FTP

Tags: uploads, ftp

Recently, I change my host server. that causing a problem.
When I want upload a new theme or plugin instead of using dashboard uploader want me to enter FTP host and username and password, What I can do to come back to the previous uploader?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're on a shared server, it's unlikely your host will correct this issue, but you can add the [upgrade constants](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants) to your wp-config file so it will at least stop asking every time.

Comment: thank a lot I use `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` on wp-config

Comment: didn't know about that. nice way....

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your hosting providers configuration this could be the result of permissions issues on your account. Sounds like httpd (i.e. Apache) is running in a different security context than your user account.

Typically this means that httpd can't write to files or directories within your document root.

Open a ticket with your provide and ask them to check the permissions and httpd/user context.

Comment: I have access to cpanel, what i can do?

Comment: Unless you're on a Virtual Private Server there's not a lot you can do yourself. You'll need the help of your hosting company to resolve this.

Answer (score -3):

Using FTP give 0777 permitions to you **wp-content** (for future created nested **upgrade** directory and nested **themes** directory. Also check are you able to upload any files to server (in not do same for **uploads** folder). Givivng 0777 permistions to **plugins** directory and all files inside - will enable edition of files via Interface.

Comment: This may be a valid approach for testing/debugging in an isolated environment; but it is extremely risky on a publicly accessible server or a shared hosting environment.

Comment: I have 0777 to theme and plugins directory but ask me for FTP account

Comment: @Stephen - someone has to be able to traverse into your html directory to be able to write to your server, it being a publicly accessible or shared server doesn't necessarily make it dangerous if it's properly chrooted.

Comment: @Milo I understand your point. But in principle why remove a layer of protection? Are you not relinquishing what little control that you have an putting your faith entirely in the hands of your hosting provider?

Comment: @Stephen - I agree, however in some cases one may not have other options. If your site is critical to your business, you should have proper hosting anyway :)

Comment: @Milo With a [`PUT` request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6) anyone can write via HTTP into such a directory.

Comment: @toscho - If the server has been configured to accept put requests and has a handler to handle them. I've never encountered such a default configuration. In any case, it's always best to consult your host.